# vector<vector> as a quick-traversal 2d data structure

Tags: vector, data-structures, time-complexity

I'm currently considering the implementation of a 2D data structure to allow me to store and draw objects in correct Z-Order (GDI+, entities are drawn in call order). The requirements are loosely:

- Ability to add new objects to the top of any depth index
- Ability to remove arbitrary object
- (Ability to move object to the top of new depth index, accomplished by 2 points above)
- Fast in-order and reverse-order traversal

As the main requirement is speed of traversal across the full data, the first thing that came to mind was an array like structure, eg. vector. It also easily allows for pushing new objects (removing objects not so great..). This works perfectly fine for our requirements, as it just so happens that the bulk of drawable entities don't change, and the ones that do sit at the top end of the order.

However it got me thinking of the implications for more dynamic requirements:

- A vector will resize itself as required -> as the 'depth' vectors would need to be maintained contiguously in memory (top-level vector enforces it), this could lead to some pretty expensive vector resizes. Worst case all vectors need to be moved to new memory location, average case requiring all vectors up the chain to be moved.
- Vectors will often hold a buffer at the end for adding new objects -> traversal could still easily force a cache miss while jumping between 'depth' vectors, rendering the top-level vector's contiguous memory less beneficial

Could someone confirm that these observations are indeed correct, making a vector a mostly very expensive structure for storing larger dynamic data sets?

From my thoughts above, I end up deducing that while traversing the whole dataset, specifically jumping between different vectors in the top-level vector, you might as well use any other data structure with inferior traversal complexity, or similar random access complexity (linked_list; map). Traversal would effectively be the same, as we might as well assume the cache misses will happen anyway, and we save ourselves a lot of bother by not keeping the depth vectors contiguously in memory.

Would that indeed be a good solution? If I'm not mistaken, on a 1D problem space, this would come down to what's more important traversal or addition/removal, vector or linked-list. On a 2D space I'm not so sure it is so black and white.

I'm wondering what sort of application requires good traversal across a 2D space, without compromising data addition/removal, and what sort of data structures are used there.

P.S. I just noticed I'm completely ignoring space-complexity, so might as well keep on ignoring it (unless you feel like adding more insight :D)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first assumption is somewhat incorrect.
Instead of thinking of vectors as the blob of memory itself, think of it as a *pointer* to automatically managed blob of memory and some metadata to keep track of it.  A vector itself is a *fixed* size, the memory it keeps track of isn't.  (See this example, note that the size of the vector object is constant: https://ideone.com/3mwjRz)

A vector of vectors can be thought of as an array of pointers.  Resizing what the pointers point to doesn't mean you need to resize the array that contains them.  The promise of items being contiguous still holds: the parent array has all of the pointers adjacent to each other and each pointer points to a contiguous chunk of memory.  However, it's not guaranteed that the end of `arr[0][N-1]` is adjacent to the beginning of `arr[1][0]`.  (To this end, your second point is correct.)

Comment: Aaaaah, so a vector is really only a handle to a memory chunk, which is guaranteed to be contiguous. Effectively meaning the only truly contiguous memory multi-dimensional structure would be an array, making random-access to held vectors (and possibly insertion if we want to dynamically add/remove vectors) the only meaningful metric.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that a Linked List would be more appropriate as you will always be traversing the whole list (vectors are good for random access). Linked lists inserts and removal are very cheap and the traversal isn't that different from a vector traversal. Maybe you should consider a Doubly Linked List as you want to traverse it in both ways.